# RLE encoding without count() method

Tags: python, string

I am trying to take a string as an input, and then output each letter with a repetition value. For example: `aaab` should output `3a1b`. But I cannot use `count()` to do this.

I have tried to code it, but I am confused because I have used more for loops and if statements than my brain can process:

```
def rle_encode(str):
    count = 1
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if i != len(str):
            if str[i] == str[i+1]:
                count += 1
                str = str[i].replace(str[i],'')
                str = str[i+1].replace(str[i+1],'')
                continue
            else:
                print(str(count) + str(str[i]))
                rle_encode(str)

        else:
            break
```

I get the following error for the line `str = str[i+1].replace(str[i+1],'')`:

> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Mmm, part of my brain thinks "`count` is out, but it doesn't mention `Counter`" :)

Comment: roganjosh would importing a library not be a lot slower?

Comment: What version of Python? Can we rely on dictionary ordering (3.6+)?

Comment: roganjosh yes I am using 3.7.

Comment: That entirely depends. For this task, maybe, because the list is so small. But this is part of the standard library and I would never think twice about importing `collections` if I thought it would help. Regardless, we can do this without that module just using dictionaries

Comment: Don't try to modify `str` in place, it makes your `i` index become invalid. Build up a *new* output string from scratch and return it at the end. And lose that recursive call, it doesn't make sense to iterate over the whole string *and* use tail recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I figured out that the answer I received did not function as an RLE, I finally managed to create my own program for those looking for an actual solution:

### Solution

```
# code
def rle_encode(string):
    string = list(string)
    string.append("")
    output = []
    x = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if i < len(string) - 1:
            if (string[i] in string) is True:
                x += 1
            if string[i] != string[i + 1]:
                if x != 1:
                    output.append(str(x) + string[i])
                    x = 0
                else:
                    output.append(string[i])
                    x = 0
    return output

output = rle_encode("aaabaaacbcc")

print(''.join(output))

# output

>>> 3ab3acb2c
```

Comment: My apologies for the incorrect answer originally, I didn't realise it needed to accommodate repeated values separately. I have corrected my answer to show you another way.

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be homework I'll stop short of rewriting the method for you, but I'll point out an *algorithm* that you can implement yourself.

- Start with an output string set to the empty string, previous character set to `None`, and previous character count set to 0.
- For each character in the string:

  - If the character is the same as the previous character, increment the previous character count, and do nothing else.
  - If it's different:

    - If there is a previous character (it's not `None`), append the count and the previous character to the output string.
    - Set the previous character to the current character, and the count to 1.
- After the loop is done, if the previous character count is nonzero, append the count and the previous character to the output string.
- Return the output string.

Some important things about this algorithm:

1. It doesn't use recursion. A recursive version would *also* work, but iteration is simpler here. Your function tries to iterate over the string *and* call itself recursively, which is confused.
2. It doesn't print. Trying to compute the result *and* print it in the same function is a common mistake of beginning programmers. It frequently leads to confusion. If your function computes the result and returns it, you can always just `print(rle_encode(str))` to get the result on screen, but you *also* have the option to store it for later, and you don't have to worry so much about order of operations (especially with recursion — it's easy for a recursive function to end up printing its results backwards, interleaved, or multiple times!)
3. It doesn't modify `str`. As a general rule, immutable data is easier to reason about than mutable data. More specifically, it's good to avoid modifying something while you're looping over it, especially modifying the *length* of something you're looping over. This is the cause of the error you see — you let `i` loop over all of the original indices of `str`, but you're making `str` shorter at the same time. Without careful correction, this causes two problems: skipping part of the input, and trying to read past the end of the input. Leaving the input unmodified and writing to a separate output string may use slightly more memory, but it means that you don't need to reason about an input that's constantly changing.

Comment: "Since this appears to be homework" I'll note that it's a popular interview question, or at least, it's a popular interview practice question on those types of sites, and it's also in the Cracking the Coding Interview book, so it may not be HW. Either way, if it's for interview practice, probably still best to have the method and implement until you get it right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools` to ensure that the ordering of the letters is considered when computing the RLE.

```
from itertools import groupby

my_string = 'aaabbcaa'

groups = groupby(my_string)

output = ''.join(str(len(list(group))) + k for k, group in groups)
print(output)
```

Which gives:

```
'3a2b1c2a'
```

If you don't want the `'1'` values, then you can `replace` them with blank spaces:

```
output = output.replace('1', '')
```

I did some timings for a 10,000 character string since I was curious about how costly the second pass over the list was for `replace` for the sake of being succinct in code (you can't grab the `len()` of the same group twice in a list comprehension because the iterator gets exhausted):

```
import numpy as np

from itertools import groupby


my_string = ''.join(np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 10000, 
                                     replace=True))

def with_replace(my_string):
    groups = groupby(my_string)
    output = ''.join([str(len(list(group))) + k for k, group in groups])
    output = output.replace('1', '')
    return output


def without_replace(string):
    groups = groupby(my_string)
    output = []
    for letter, group in groups:
        length = len(list(group))
        if length > 1:
            output.append(str(length))
        else:
            output.append('')
        output.append(letter)
    output = ''.join(output)
    return output


def your_way(string):
    string = list(string)
    string.append("")
    output = []
    x = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if i < len(string) - 1:
            if (string[i] in string) is True:
                x += 1
            if string[i] != string[i + 1]:
                if x != 1:
                    output.append(str(x) + string[i])
                    x = 0
                else:
                    output.append(string[i])
                    x = 0
    output = ''.join(output)
    return output
```

Giving:

```
%timeit with_replace(my_string)
8.63 ms ± 243 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit without_replace(my_string)
7.79 ms ± 45.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit your_way(my_string)
8.91 ms ± 92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: What this does isn't RLE at all. For instance if you give it `aabbaa` it will output `4a2b` when the correct result is `2a2b2a`.

Comment: @hobbs fair, I was only working towards the output the OP mentioned, I don't actually know what RLE is. I had already been marked correct so I'm not sure whether I should change it

Comment: @hobbs I'll put both methods but at work atm so won't have chance to fix it until this evening. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @hobbs I fixed my approach.